# Display Open/Closed in real time in rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there I'm trying to create a open or closed display in a rails app I have two models Establishments and Opentimes. Here are my DB tables.I'm using MySQL as my database.

```
create_table "establishments", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "tagline"
  t.text     "description",    limit: 65535
  t.string   "postcode"
  t.string   "address_line_1"
  t.string   "address_line_2"
  t.string   "address_line_3"
  t.string   "parish"
  t.string   "phone_number"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_establishments_on_user_id", using: :btree
end

create_table "opentimes", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.integer  "day"
  t.string   "label"
  t.time     "open"
  t.time     "closed"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.integer  "establishment_id"
end
```

I have a relationship set between the two models and nested the routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :users
 resources :establishments do
  resources :opentimes
 end
 root to: "establishments#index"
end
```

And here is the method I am trying to execute to no avail in my establishments model.

```
class Establishment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :opentimes

 def open?
    day_of_week_number = Time.current.strftime("%u")
    opentime = @opentimes.find_by(day: day_of_week_number)
    if (opentime.open.strftime("%H:%M") >= Time.current.strftime("%H:%M")) && (Time.curent.strftime("%H:%M") < opentime.closed.strftime("%H:%M"))
        'Open'
    else
        'Closed'
    end
 end
end
```

If anyone could help me and point me in the right direction with this I would be very grateful. Please forgive me if I'm way off with this I'm a newbie to rails and programming. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are wrong and there is a typo in it. Coded exactly as I say it in English:

It is open if the `current_time` is past (greater than) the open time:
`Time.current.strftime("%H:%M") >= opentime.open.strftime("%H:%M")`

It is open if the `current_time` is before (less than) the closing time:
`Time.current.strftime("%H:%M") < opentime.closed.strftime("%H:%M")`

Combine these two and let me know how it works out. Your first inequality was wrong and you spelled `current` as `curent` in your second one.

Comment: Hey jeff thanks for your feed back just combined the two errors you pointed out and getting this error:  private method `open' called for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: It's because `opentime = @opentimes.find_by(day: day_of_week_number)` is not returning anything that matches. It's returning an empty array/relation. Make sure that `opentime` is defined with a proper query and then try :)

Comment: Looked at your query, `Time.current.strftime("%u") => '3'` whereas your `day` attribute is an `integer`. You probably want `opentime = @opentimes.find_by(day: day_of_week_number).to_i`